# Took laptop apart, no longer will stay on while using battery

Tags: laptop, battery

I took my laptop apart (Acer S7 392), very carefully noting each step of disassembly, in order to replace the keyboard.  Now the laptop will not sustain power unless the charger is plugged in.  I checked the single battery connector, it is plugged in securely and no pins are broken, and I don't see any relevant settings in the BIOS (which does reset each time the battery is disconnected).  On Linux, I see the battery level reading stick at 81%, which makes me think that's just some default setting resulting from a failing reading.    It will shut down in Linux, Windows, or in the BIOS itself, if unplugged.

What should I check?  I am fairly certain nothing was scratched or damaged.

Update: output from "upower" on Linux:

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SANYO
  model:                AP13F3N
  serial:               448
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 02 Jun 2015 06:49:06 PM EDT (6 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    energy:              34.62 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         42.54 Wh
    energy-full-design:  47.1 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             8.219 V
    percentage:          81%
    capacity:            90.3185%
    technology:          lithium-ion
  History (charge):
    1433285251  81.000  discharging
    1433285250  0.000   unknown
  History (rate):
    1433285250  0.000   unknown
```

Comment: Does the battery level also show 81% when the battery is disconnected? (I want to know if it acts differently with the battery connected vs not connected.)

Comment: If your laptop is on and plugged in, and you pull the battery out, what happens?

Comment: It shows no battery meter at all when the battery isn't plugged in (presumably the interface no longer exists).

Comment: If I unplug it, it stays on, but the meter disappears (this is an obscure battery meter reading a Linux interface).

Comment: Question updated w/ more info

Comment: Do you have any method of checking the charge on the battery outside of plugging it into your computer?

Comment: I have a multimeter somewhere (I think), but there's a ~10pin connector for the battery, would be pretty difficult to rig up.  So no.

Comment: Obviously the laptop can tell the difference between the battery there or not, so this might be a classic case of "laptop battery detected but not charging". I assume when you ran the power upower you were plugged in, yet it shows "discharging" rather than "charging", so this confirms my guess. There are a lot of reasons that could cause this. All are hardware related. (Dirty battery contacts, motherboard charging circuit, even bad battery though that seems unlikely since it worked before you dismantled the laptop.) But maybe something got knicked while removing the keyboard....

Comment: I'll be shocked if this works, but it's worth a try. I heard someone say they fixed a non-charging battery by turning on the laptop without the battery in, and then inserting the battery while the laptop was on. I have no idea why that would work though...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be due to a badly implemented Acer design feature. On the reverse side, there are a series of Torx screws. If the hardware detects any are open, it kills power as a "safety" feature. This is done to reduce the risk of a fire should the user open the case and turn on power to the laptop. This sounds nice, but the feature has been implemented poorly because the screws are self-loosing over time! Try tightening the screws hard. A Torx screwdriver (with changeable heads) can be picked up from a good hardware store for a few dollars.

If you did not replace (or sufficiently tighten) any of the Torx screw, then this is could be your problem.

The problem (with resolution) is [described in great detail here](https://superuser.com/questions/1008809/laptop-shuts-down-suddenly-when-running-on-battery).

Comment: Actually, I'm typing on the laptop right now, and several screws are missing (and have been since I posted this question).

Comment: Possibly the case-open sensor is only fitted to a subset of the screws? My S7-392 definitely would not work reliably on battery until all screws were well tightened. However, I did tighten them all at once (not one at a time).